# Handwriting recognition for different language using InkManager, C# XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, inkmanager

I am writing a Windows 8.1 app in which I'm using InkManager to recognize handwriting. It's working fine when I'm recognizing English Words but I've no idea how to recognize different language words like Urdu, hindi, chinese using inkmanager

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.inking.inkrecognizer.name.aspx) you can see the supported languages. There is Chinese both traditional and simplified but no Urdu or Hindi.

Answer (score 0):

Check "Step 2: Set a default language for recognition" from MSDN. It supports many languages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700417.aspx